# Android - Jetpack compose missing references

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to follow the official google Jetpack compose tutorial on this [url](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial) but Android studio have an issue resolving the modifier **Height()**

I am 100% sure that I have imported the correct dependencies as per the tutorial, however, this modifier is no where to be found. It is not deprecated as it is still references in the official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/layout/package-summary#Height(androidx.ui.core.Dp))

```
fun NewsStory() {
    val image = +imageResource(R.drawable.header)
        Column(
            modifier = Spacing(16.dp)
            ) {
            Container(modifier = Height(180.dp) wraps Expanded) {
                DrawImage(image)
            }

            HeightSpacer(16.dp)

            Text("A day in Shark Fin Cove")
            Text("Davenport, California")
            Text("December 2018")
        }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using `dev02`(because Google's documentation is not updated) dependency for **ui-layout** dependency, because **Height()** is added in **dev03**. Change your ui-layout dependency to **dev03**:

```
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev03'
```

It should work

Comment: I was using the right dependency `dev03` but it was an issue with my IDE. I guess gradle caches was somehow holding reference to the previous dependency `dev02`. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the following to get things running:

```
//app/build.gradle
...
dependencies {

    ...                                                                   

    //Jetpack Compose
    implementation 'androidx.compose:compose-compiler:0.1.0-dev09'
    implementation 'androidx.compose:compose-runtime:0.1.0-dev09'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev09'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev09'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev09'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev09'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my setup as far as Jetpack Compose Dependencies go. You don't need all of them so feel free to skip the super specific ones - https://github.com/vinaygaba/Learn-Jetpack-Compose-By-Example/blob/master/build.gradle#L24

Pasting it here for reference

```
'compose': [
                    'composeComplier': "androidx.compose:compose-compiler:${versions.compose}",
                    'composeRuntime': "androidx.compose:compose-runtime:${versions.compose}",
                    'core': "androidx.ui:ui-core:${versions.compose}",
                    'foundation': "androidx.ui:ui-foundation:${versions.compose}",
                    'tooling': "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:${versions.compose}",
                    'layout': "androidx.ui:ui-layout:${versions.compose}",
                    'material': "androidx.ui:ui-material:${versions.compose}",
                    'savedInstanceState': "androidx.ui:ui-saved-instance-state:${versions.compose}",
                    'uiTest': "androidx.ui:ui-test:${versions.compose}",
                    'uiLiveData': "androidx.ui:ui-livedata:${versions.compose}"
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Geoff Langenderfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8033562/geoff-langenderfer) said changing to `dev09` from `dev03` worked.

```
//app/build.gradle
 dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev09'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev09'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev09'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev09'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
```